# Make table row editable using jQuery, jEditable, jeditable-rails gem or any AJAXy solution

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jeditable

I have a table with rows of data on it. I want most of the row to be editable by clicking either the row itself or an edit button.

Let's say I have a table that lists products:

- Product Name
- Brand
- Model
- Price

I'm able to accomplish this by using jQuery and jEditable; and also by using the jeditable-rails gem. But I can only edit one cell at a time.

What I need is this: If I click in the Edit button or the row itself. All those four cells in the table should become editable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323830/how-can-i-make-the-full-row-editable-with-jeditable-plugin

Comment: I tried using that code but wasn't able to get it working. I'm not sure what he means by var jeditableEvent = $.fn.editable.defaults.event;

I'm trying to use jQuery

Comment: I tried this also, but makes the whole table row editable, including the tr and td tags.

`code`
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".editlink").click(function() {
    $("table tr").editable('http://localhost',{});
  });
});
`code`

Comment: I never worked with jEditable, but try changing $('table tr') to $('table tr td')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('td:not(.edit)').editable('', {
    onblur: 'ignore',
    submit: 'ok',
    cancel: 'cancel',
    width: 75,
    event: 'edit'
});

$('td').click(function(e) {
    // reset all editables
    var allEditables = $(this).closest('table').find('td:not(.edit)').get();
    $.each(allEditables, function(i, elm) {
        elm.reset();
    });

    // make all cells in this row editable
    $(this).parent().children(':not(.edit)').trigger('edit');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UMccc/221/

Comment: @JimG. thanks for your negative vote, making this group of answers look rather amusing! :D On the serious side, could you please come up with at least some suggestion while you downvoted an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the right path here: [jQuery - Edit a table row inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463572/jquery-edit-a-table-row-inline)

It doesn't use jEditable.

It's just a Javascript function, but I think it's launch pad for creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to use and flexible [jquery inline editable plugin](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/7/jQuery-Editable-Plugin-Best-In-Place-Editor-.html). It let's you to have editable easily anywhere, inside a table or h1 tag, and can covnert anything to anything. actually the idea behind is simple and kinda unique.

Cheers,