# Targetting a <td> from it's parents <tr> with data-attributes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing an editable table feature as described in a previous post: [Editable row in a table - is using the record ID on a <tr> element bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490040/editable-row-in-a-table-is-using-the-record-id-on-a-tr-element-bad-practice)

I've got the following markup:

```
<tr data-id="2">
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td><button class="editBtn">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="3">
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td><button class="editBtn">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

Using jquery I've been able to work out which row I'm editing by targeting the `.editBtn` and then using the following to work out which is the `data-id` element:

```
$('.editBtn').click(function() {
    id = ($(this).closest('tr').data('id'));
    console.log(id);
});
```

What I don't understand is given this ID how can I then target the `td` element which has my category name in it (Foo and Bar, in this example)?

I want to be able to take the content in these and place them in an editable field thus:

```
<td><input type="text" value="Foo"></td>
```

I also need to be able to change the 'Edit' button to a 'Save' button at this point, with a different class name, e.g.

```
<td><button class="saveBtn">Save</button></td>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: for the saveBtn make it display:none then when needed show it and hide the editBtn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find()` along with `:first` (or `:eq(0)`) to get the first `td` within the row. You can also change the text and class of the clicked button using `text()` and `addClass()` respectively. Finally you can place the content in an `input` by appending it to the `td`. Try this:

```js
$('.editBtn').click(function() {
  var $button = $(this).addClass('save').text('Save');
  var $tr = $button.closest('tr');
  var id = $tr.data('id');
  var $td = $tr.find('td:first');
  
  $td.html('<input value="' + $td.text() + '" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="2">
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>
      <button class="editBtn">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="3">
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>
      <button class="editBtn">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good job KFC king.

Comment: and if the html can change one day it's better to give a class to the td with the name lets say the class is name then access it $tr.find('.name')

Comment: I think he need's HTML5 contenteditable attribute of tables.

Comment: @user2521387 feel free to add your own answer. I wouldn't call this wrong at all. If you want to use `contenteditable` I wish you the best of luck getting it working reliably in IE on a `td` element, and also re-inventing the wheel when serialising the `form` contents before sending, as when using this method you can just call the `serialize()` method.

Comment: Keep the comments civil and constructive please people.