# .click function will only work inside a parent .click function and cannot be executed outside it

Tags: jquery, html

I've been developing an application which allows table rows to be edited using jquery. The original post is here [Targetting a <td> from it's parents <tr> with data-attributes using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491487/targetting-a-td-from-its-parents-tr-with-data-attributes-using-jquery)

The flow of the application is:

1. Table is loaded.
2. 'Edit' button (with a class `editBtn`) appears on each row.
3. Clicking the 'Edit' button removes the class `editBtn` and adds a class `saveBtn`. The text is also changed from 'Edit' to 'Save'.

The intention is that when clicking the Save button I can do an ajax request.

However, I can only target the `.saveBtn` being clicked if the jquery for it resides *inside* the original `.click` function on `.editBtn`. So for example, **this works**:

```
$('.editBtn').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this).addClass('save').text('Save');
    var $tr = $button.closest('tr');
    var id = $tr.data('id');
    var $td = $tr.find('td:first');
    var $td2 = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)');

    $td.html('<input value="' + $td.text() + '" />');
    $td2.html('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success saveBtn">Save</button>');

    $('.saveBtn').click(function() {
        console.log('savebtn');
    });
});
```

But **this does not** work:

```
$('.editBtn').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this).addClass('save').text('Save');
    var $tr = $button.closest('tr');
    var id = $tr.data('id');
    var $td = $tr.find('td:first');
    var $td2 = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)');

    $td.html('<input value="' + $td.text() + '" />');
    $td2.html('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success saveBtn">Save</button>');

});

// Moved outside $('.editBtn').click
    $('.saveBtn').click(function() {
        console.log('savebtn');
    });
```

Why is this?

Comment: Update your code to use the on("click@, function()...) format as this works for dynamic elements where .click() does not. This is the gist of the duplicate to which @SatPal has sent you.

Comment: @Satpal I disagree with this being marked as a duplicate. Whilst I can see there are parallels with that post and mine, there's no way I would have been able to find it based off a search anyway. The answer given below is helpful to this situation.

Comment: @Andy, This is duplicate as you are creating _dynamically_ , Solution is provided in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you are appending .savebtn after click event is bind. you have to use document on click.
this will work:-

```
$('.editBtn').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this).addClass('save').text('Save');
    var $tr = $button.closest('tr');
    var id = $tr.data('id');
    var $td = $tr.find('td:first');
    var $td2 = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)');

    $td.html('<input value="' + $td.text() + '" />');
    $td2.html('<button class="btn btn-primary btn-success saveBtn">Save</button>');

});

// Moved outside $('.editBtn').click
    $(document).on('click', '.saveBtn', function(){ 
        console.log('savebtn');
    });
```